# Converting / parsing column strings to datetime values - pandas

Tags: python, string, datetime, pandas

I have a csv output of thermal simulations, which I would like to perform data analysis on, using pandas.

Having imported the csv into a pandas dataframe, I would like to manipulate the timestamp and import it as such.

The starting format is the following (starts with a space, has US data format and year is missing).

```
    ' 05/01  01:00:00'
    ' 05/01  02:00:00'
    ' 05/01  03:00:00'
    ' 05/01  04:00:00'
    ' 05/01  05:00:00'
```

I was adviced to address it with a loop function, which I wrote as follows:

```
timestamp = []
for ns in raw_datetime:
    #timestamp.append(ns[5:7] + '.' + ns[2:4] + '_' + ns[9:11] + '00h')
    timestamp.append('2016' + '/' + ns[2:4] + '/' + ns[5:7] + '_' + ns[9:11] + ':00')
```

where

```
raw_datetime = df[' Date/Time']  #original data column
```

This works fine and returns the datetime format I want.

```
['2016/05/01_01:00', '2016/05/01_02:00', '2016/05/01_03:00', '2016/05/01_04:00']
```

However this appears not be usable by **pd.to_datetime** function, as that seems to require a list rather than a series(?).

I came across the concept of parsing and and fuctions wuch as:

```
 raw_datetime.str.extract('string', expand=True)
```

however, I am not sure how I could do that, while flipping month and day AND adding year 2016 info which is not present in the raw data.

Thanks!

Edit: code added below
N.B. native format is '  05/01  01:00:00' i.e.: double space, month, day,double space, hh, mm, ss)]

first attempt

```
df = pd.read_csv('./SimResults.csv')
a = pd.to_datetime(df[' Date/Time'], format='  %m/%d  %H:%M:%s')
```

Second attempt:

```
df = pd.read_csv('./SimResults.csv')
raw_datetime = df[' Date/Time'].str.lstrip('  ')
raw_datetime = ('2016/') + raw_datetime   
b = pd.to_datetime(raw_datetime, format='%Y/%m/%d  %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: it should work on a series also `pd.to_datetime(df['your_new_col'])` should work

Comment: when reading the csv file use `parse_dates=['Date/Time']`, then it will automatically append `2016` to the date.

Comment: sorry guys, but none of these seem to work!

Answer (score 2):

You should specify your format to `to_datetime` function, because it isn't default format:

```
pd.to_datetime(x, format='%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M')
```

Comment: I have specified the format from my 'to_datetime' function, however I receive the error: "_time data '  05/01  01:00:00' does not match format '%Y/%m/%d_%H:%M'_
The string needs to be manipulated to be read by the 'to_datetime' command, doesn't it?

Comment: No, no need any additional manipulations. Maybe some mistype in format? You can check options here: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior.

Comment: Eugene,
it does not seem to work, I am afraid. I have tried so many options and I dont know what else to do.

Would you be happy to check my code?

Comment: I have added two bits of code to the question. Thanks